# Hook Conexion SSL a través de Proxy

Tags: c++

Quiero que una aplicacion usa un proxy determinado y lo hize con DLL Inyeccion el problema es que solo conecta peticiones no-https, hookee la funcion *connect* de **ws2_32**, el problema es que cuando hookeo el connect cambia la ip destino por la del proxy y va bien con las conexiones no cifradas(http) pero cuando hago peticiones https deberia ser *connect www.google.com:443* pero la dll solo cambia la ip de *connect* y al proxy llega encryptado el resto sin realizar el tunel.

HOOK

```
VOID WINAPI ProcessSockaddrIn(const struct sockaddr *name) {
if (name->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    struct sockaddr_in *sin = (sockaddr_in*)name;
    unsigned int ip;
    WORD port;
    ip = sin->sin_addr.s_addr;
    port = htons(sin->sin_port);
    if (port == 80 || port == 443) {
        port = PORT_SERVER;
        ip = inet_addr(LOCALSERVER);
        sin->sin_port = htons(port);
        sin->sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
    }
  }
}

int H_Connect(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen) {
  ProcessSockaddrIn(name);
  return rconnect(s, name, namelen);
}
```

Puede ser una previa funcion de la app que le indique que envie el *Connect* despues de hacer la conexion? Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: El proxy en cuestión soporta **modo transparente** ? si no es así, no creo que te funcione.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Trauma por la respuesta, puede ser... pero creo que se debe a la app, cuando la app se configura con proxy el envia un _connect www.google.com_ sin encriptar al proxy, pero esto no lo esta haciendo la inyeccion ya que solo cambia la IP.

Comment: Aun que lo de modo transparente tambien es solucion, pero si el proxy no lo posee que puedo hacer?

Comment: Claro, por eso lo de modo transparente. Si la app sabe que hay un proxy, hace el CONNECT. Si no lo sabe, no lo hace. Hay varias soluciones, como usar 2 proxys (uno lo configuras en la app y otro al que envías con tu HOOK, para que la app use siempre el CONNECT), o usar un proxy TCP, que solo haga el puente TCP sin mayores historias. O un proxy *transparent* HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Si, son soluciones pero lastimosamente el proxy no se puede remplazar por otro y establecer el proxy en la app no es fatible por que recibe del proxy de windows en general, talvez otra funcion que hookear que haga como si el proxy estuviera activado (La APP usa las API de windows en su mayoria).

Comment: Algo tipo _WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser t_

Comment: No puedo decirte mas, no conozco la API de Windows. Seguramente, la app consultará por el proxy ANTES de intentar conectar. Es cosa de que pruebes, o esperes a ver si alguien te contesta. Lo único que se me ocurre es que, si la app consulta por la config del proxy ANTES de cada conexión, provoques un fallo, para forzarla a reintentar, y aproveches para cambiar la config del proxy, sabiendo que el siguiente intento será a la misma ip. Cuando cierre el socket, restauras la config del proxy.

Comment: Ok, Muchas gracias Igual!!!, voy a ver si pillo la funcione previa o despues que hace eso, y esperar quien tenga la solucion, saludos.

Comment: Una última cosa. ¿ No estarás intentando engañar a **un navegador WEB**, verdad ? eso es **mucho más facil**, ya vienen preparados para eso.

Comment: No estiendo, es Facil o no se puede ?

Comment: Si es **a un navegador web**, por ejemplo `Internet Explorer` no tienes ni que programar nada. Busca sobre `Proxy Auto-Configuration`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Necko/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file Eso sí, tienes que poder tocar el servidor DHCP. Si no puedes tocarlo, a *programar* toca.

Comment: Gracias, pero es para _chrome_

Comment: También vale para Chrome. Te recomiendo que lo uses, mucho mas simple que lo que estás haciendo. Te deja escoger un proxy concreto para una determinada dirección. Haz otra pregunta, tipo ¿ como usar PAC para seleccionar un proxy para una determinada URL en Chrome ?

Comment: Gracias @Trauma pero el objectio es generalizado por eso la DLL, hace parte de un programa que sirve precisamente para redireccionar trafico y no se puede limitar a PAC por que debe obtener reglas del programa principal.

Comment: @Trauma Puedes ver este link donde hay una discucion y hay mas codigo si me puedes ayudar http://pushedx.net/d/184-obtener-puntero-de-connectex/6

Comment: Esas no son formas; crea tu pregunta, y, si puedo y tengo los conocimientos, con gusto la responderé. Te sugiero que expongas la *lógica* de lo que quieres hacer, junto con un breve resumen de los pasos intentados. Puede incluso que alguien **mas cualificado que yo** (que estoy en continuo aprendizaje) te responda :-)